# Port Forwarding is not working

Tags: networking, router, ssh, port-forwarding, port

I want to be able to connect to my Raspberry Pi either via ssh or through connection like server-client from WAN which I think I need to do with port forwarding which is what I'm having problems with.

I just adjusted my router's port forwarding to be as shown below ( external ip address i.e public ip was changed so I don't dox myself).

[image]

I have made static ip address on my Raspberry Pi and changed listening (ssh) port to 2525 and I'm still unable to achieve connection when doing something like: `ssh user@public_ip -p 2525`

This is my firewall protection

[image]

My router is "Ubee WI-FI Modem" and I haven't found any documentation about it

What else could cause a problem when port forwarding besides what's on the router's page about pw?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Am I guessing right that your actual 'external' IP address starts with `100.16.`?

Comment: restart the router maybe &or rpi

Comment: @u1686_grawity yes, in my understanding that's public ip, the one used to access my pi.

Comment: @Petepf been there done that, doesn't fix the issue

Comment: @ZombieSpale: Right, but the main questions are 1) is your 'public' address **specifically in the range** between `100.64.x.x` and `100.127.x.x`?, and 2) is it the same address as what you see at https://www.my-ip.io/?

Comment: To be clear, when you run `ssh user@public_ip -p 2525` and it fails, are you doing this from outside your local network? Or from another host on the same network as the pi? What is the exact error message or other behavior that you get when you try this command?

Comment: Okay so it seems that when I do ssh user@public_ip from my local network I achieve connection but when I try from outside of my network I just get a timed out

Comment: @u1686_grawity no, it starts with 178.149…. And it is same as my-ip.io

Comment: Good, that rules out CGNAT (the most common problem); the next most likely explanation is "NAT hairpin" (which also has a few existing threads here).

Comment: @u1686_grawity so from what I've figured out is that NAT hairpin is accessing LAN device with external ip but I can't seem to figure or find any info on what settings to change in my previously shown screenshots so that I can connect to pi from outside of my network

Comment: Please use the answers that you have given in the comments and edit and improve your question.  It does not make sense to me.

Answer (score -1):

- While you could use 2525 as external port for SSH on your modem, internally I would use 22. If you keep 2525 internally, can you connect to the laptop on 2525 from another laptop?
- SSH uses TCP
- Your RPi might have an active firewall. Disable that to make sure it isn't the problem here.